# How to use knockout.js afterRender

Tags: javascript, ajax, knockout.js

I've read the documentation for afterRender in knockout.js but I am confused how to apply it in my case.

```
<form id="shortlistForm" data-bind="style: { display: !koIsShortlisted() ? 'inline-block' : 'none'}, attr: {action: '@(MVC.GetLocalUrl(MVC.HireOrgJobApplication.ViewApplication(Model.CurrentOrganization.CustomUrl, Model.Job.JobKey, "xxx/ajax-shortlist")))'.replace('xxx', application.applicationKey)}" method="post" style="display:inline;">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <input type="hidden" name="ApplicationKey" data-bind="attr:{ value : application.applicationKey }" />
            <button type="submit" class="btn-act jui-tooltip" title="Shortlist">
                <i class="fa fa-2x fa-star"></i>
            </button>
</form>
```

I have this form that shortlists an application. Since it displays only when "koIsShorlisted" is false, it should disappear when I click it.

Notice that "koIsShortlisted" is inside a viewModel called "filteredApplications" and there are more than one object in this viewModel just as the screenshot shows.

[image]

It does work when I try to do it only for one application.

```
                    $('form#shortlistForm').ajaxForm(function () {
                        viewModel.filteredApplications()[0].koIsShortlisted(false);

                    });
```

I just used this function to make the first object's "koIsShortlisted" to false.

But since there are more than one applications(objects) in the viewModel, I want to use foreach, afterRender to make this work for all objects.

How can I use foreach, afterRender and how can I write a function that goes inside (afterRender) that calls filteredApplication.koIsShortlisted(false) for each object?

Help!

Comment: Do you want to change all `koIsShortlisted` observable properties inside each element of the  `viewModel.filteredApplications()` observable array?  If the code you show in your question works, you could replace `viewModel.filteredApplications()[0].koIsShortlisted(false);` with this:  
 `$.each(viewModel.filteredApplications(), function() { this.koIsShortlisted (false);})`

Comment: Please see: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44642540/how-does-knockout-js-afterrender-work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44642540/how-does-knockout-js-afterrender-work)