# How does knockout.js afterRender work?

Tags: jquery, ajax, knockout.js

The documentation of afterRender of knockout.js is not clear to me.
What is the purpose of it and how do we have to use it?
What are some main usage examples?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When do we need to use afterRender of Knockout.js and How do we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44644730/when-do-we-need-to-use-afterrender-of-knockout-js-and-how-do-we-use-it)

Comment: Looks like you re-asked this question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44644730/when-do-we-need-to-use-afterrender-of-knockout-js-and-how-do-we-use-it ? I've voted to close this one as a dupe of your later one.

Comment: This question now has an answer but the other one does not, so I have transferred by close vote to the other question. @user7677413 now you have an answer for this could you maybe close your other one? It just helps other people if they can find questions that have accepted answers, rather than finding unanswered questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knockout **afterRender** is invoked each time the foreach block is duplicated and inserted into the document, both when foreach first initializes, and when new entries are added to the associated array later. This can be costly when there is heavy logic involved while using a foreach.

**afterAdd** — is like **afterRender**, except it is invoked only when new entries are added to your array (and not when foreach first iterates over your array’s initial contents). A common use for **afterAdd** is to call a method such as jQuery’s $(domNode).fadeIn() so that you get animated transitions whenever items are added.

Use **afterAdd** if you only need code to run after a 'NEW' item had been added to the array.

To avoid this expensive form of running code after each item is added to the UI, create a custom binding handler to run after the page has been loaded.

Below is one I used to hide the form on pageLoad. Of course you can tell it to do what you want with options for initialization and update.

**Sample Code:**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.pageLoad = {
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data, context) {
    var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
    $(element).hide(value);

},
update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {     
}};
```

Also check out: **afterRemove**, **beforeMove**, and **afterMove** [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html)!

Markup on your selected element:

```
data-bind="pageLoad: function() { hideForm() }"
```

The javascript code:

```
self.hideForm = function () {
        $("#form").hide("slide", 500);
};
```

Comment: Thanks. So are you saying that the function inside "foreach: { afterRender: ___ }" will be applied for each element in whatever it's inside "foreach: { data: ____ }" ? If so, how do we have to use it if we want to pass a viewModel and run a function to each of its element? For example, let's say I am passing a viewModel 'A' and I want to run function "F" on each of its element. How can we do that?

Comment: _Here is an example:_ data-bind="afterRender: function () { F() }" *Make sure you define F as a function in ViewModel A. My example to go with the example above is data-bind="pageLoad: function () { hideForm() }". This calls the binding handler that I customized. The best part about knockout is the ease and comfort of custom bindings to do your bidding.

Comment: I think you are missing the link

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I still dont get how to use in my specific case. I added my code on my question. I would be great if you can take a look at it.

Comment: Add custom binding handler and call it 'filterForm' or something like that. Change the afterRender to call the custom filterForm: and on the init: add your renderApplication function.

Comment: ko.bindingHandlers.yourBindingName = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // This will be called when the binding is first applied to an element
        // Set up any initial state, event handlers, etc. here
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // This will be called once when binding is first applied to an element,
        // and again whenever any observables that are accessed change
        // Update the DOM element based on the supplied values here.
    }
};

Comment: sorry i really appreciate your answer, but I am new to javascript and knockout especially, so could you please help me writing that part of code?